# Simple python COM server to expose scipy integration to VBA

Tags: python, beginner, vba, com

I want to create a COM server to expose scipy to VBA code, as performing integration is kinda difficult and I don't know of any good VBA/COM libraries for this. My objectives are:

- As portable as possible
- Fast
- Maintainable

Here's the python:

```py
# Requires C:\Users\...\anaconda3\Library\bin on the PATH
from scipy import integrate
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from typing import Callable
import comtypes


class ScipyWrapper:
    # pythoncom.CreateGuid()
    _reg_clsid_ = "{A621AB64-9378-4B54-A7D3-20711C0B72DB}"
    _reg_desc_ = "Python Scipy COM Server"
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonCOM.ScipyWrapper"
    _reg_clsctx_ = comtypes.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER # don't want inproc because conda not supported on 64 bit 
                                                # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67462529/6609896

    _public_methods_ = ["quad",]
    # _public_attrs_ = []
    # _readonly_attrs_ = []

    def quad(self, vbFunc, a: float, b: float) -> float:
        vb_dispatch = Dispatch(vbFunc)
        func: Callable[[float], float] = vb_dispatch.Evaluate  # Callable[..., float]?
        return integrate.quad(func, a, b)[0]  # only return val, not uncertainty


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import win32com.server.register

    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(ScipyWrapper)
```

Called from VBA (twinBasic) like:

```vb
Module Main
    Public Sub doStuff()
        Dim integrator as Object = CreateObject("PythonCOM.ScipyWrapper")
        Dim func as IOneDimensionalFunction = New XSquared 'this is what we'll integrate
        Debug.Print integrator.quad(func, 0., 1.) 'integrate x^2 from 0->1, returns 0.333333...
    End Sub
End Module

'@Description("Interface for a f(x) -> y function, with optional parameters")
Class IOneDimensionalFunction
    Public Function Evaluate(ByVal x As Double, ParamArray parameters() as Variant) As Double
    End Function
End Class

Class XSquared
    Implements IOneDimensionalFunction
    Private Function IOneDimensionalFunction_Evaluate(ByVal x As Double, ParamArray parameters() as Variant) As Double
        Return x^2
    End Function    
End Class
```

#### Questions:

- Not sure how to Type the python, `vbFunc` is a PyIDispatch instance but not sure what that means for typing/mypy.
- I'd like to use strong typing to protect my python, right now it's duck typed and I could easily pass an Interface without the Evaluate method, or anything else for that matter.
- No idea how to handle python errors and turn them into COM errors.
- Is this ref-count safe?

OFC any other tips on general style, use of comments and naming etc. are welcome :)

Comment: What problem did you intend to solve with this? Python can do a lot of direct communication with Office software, ignoring VBA altogether.

Comment: @Mast I need the integration to do convolution of probability distributions, which I'm after for a code profiling library in VBA. I could do post processing of data in a python script but I think it's cleaner if I can import a VBA library without any kind of file IO to communicate with python, going through COM is smoother

Answer (score 2):

### Deferred Imports

Why is `import win32com.server.register` only imported during `__main__`? It should be inexpensive and clean to just leave it at the top with everything else. I'd also de-namespace `from win32com.server.register import UseCommandLine` but that's mostly a matter of taste.

### Stubbing

You ask:

> vbFunc is a PyIDispatch instance but not sure what that means for typing/mypy

If `PyIDispatch` is an importable type, then simply

```
def quad(self, vbFunc: PyIDispatch, a: float, b: float) -> float:
```

If it's not importable at all (this can happen for some libraries that are aggressively dynamic), then you basically have two options:

- Declare an opaque, named [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) to make it clear to callers that this is not just "anything"
- Do the work that the library should have done for you, and [stub it yourself](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) using a custom `.pyi`

### Call protocols

```
# Callable[..., float]?
```

You're right to be confused, and mypy is still fairly terrible at annotating variadic callables. Here you should consider using [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol):

```
class DispatchCall(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: float, *parameters: COMCompatibleTypes) -> float:
        ... # literally an ellipsis

# Later:

func: DispatchCall = vb_dispatch.Evaluate
```

### Unpacking

Re.

```
return integrate.quad(func, a, b)[0]  # only return val, not uncertainty
```

it's worth noting that uncertainty is not the only thing `quad` [returns](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html); there's actually `y`, `abserr`, `infodict`, `message` and `explain`.

It's minor, but I typically prefer to do at least a partial unpack to make it a little more clear what's happening:

```
y, *_ = integrate.quad(func, a, b)
```

Given the tuple length I don't think I'd do this, but you can if you think it adds clarity:

```
y, abserr, infodict, message, explain = integrate.quad(func, a, b)
```

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how to typehint `func` inside `quad`. if quad is `quad(func, a:float, b:float, args:Tuple)` then func *must* accept a Tuple arg (`Callable[[float,Tuple],float]`. If a tuple is not passed to quad then func *may* accept a Tuple arg `Callable[[float,Tuple],float] | Callable[[float],float] | Callable [[float, *args],float]`. There may be some @overload I can do... Moreover Evaluate really looks like`__call__(self, x: float, *args: COMCompatibleTypes) -> float:` where `COMCompatibleTypes` does not include Tuple...

Comment: ... Since the `*args` can be left out, the function sig is compatible with  `Callable[[float],float]` for func, but not `Callable[[float, Tuple],float]`. This means when I pass a tuple to quad(), I want mypy to warn me that func is expected to be  `Callable[[float, Tuple],float]` which is not compatible with  `__call__(self, x: float, *args: COMCompatibleTypes) -> float` even though that *is* compatible with the signature of func when a Tuple is not passed

Comment: Where does the `Tuple` come from? Does that correspond to `ParamArray parameters() as Variant` ?

Comment: No, `ParamArray parameters() As Variant => *args: COMCompatibleTypes`, `Tuple` comes from `scipy.integrate.quad(func, a: float, b:float, args: Tuple=(), ...)` (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html?highlight=scipy%20integrate%20romb)). Sorry yeah that was sort of confusing, hope this makes sense. FWIW COMCompatibleTypes is not something that exists yet, but COMCompatibleTypes does contain `float` which can be coerced to a COM double, whereas it does not contain `Tuple` as there is not a COM equivalent (currently)  - it would error in pywin32

Comment: I'm really confused now. Is `COMCompatibleTypes` a sequence type or an element type? For it to be used with `*` it needs to be an element type. Are you actually going to be passing in a tuple, as in `func(1.0, (2.0, 3.0))`? Or are you going to be passing in variadic arguments like `func(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`? If the latter, your hint should not be `Tuple`.

Comment: Scipy quad accepts (optional) arguments and forwards them onto func as a tuple. However my func implementation is defined in VBA to accept arguments in the variadic form with ParamArray. Consequently, as these two definitions for arguments are incompatible, I want mypy to enforce that *no additional arguments* are passed, as the variadic signature cannot be invoked with a tuple so the only way to make the 2 signatures compatible is to remove any optional arguments. COMCompatibleTypes is a Union type of a few things, for the sake of this, let's say it is `typing.Any except Tuple` (pseudo code)

Comment: Crucially, whereas [scipy quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) accepts extra arguments as a tuple, it does not _pass them on_ as a tuple. It unpacks them. This calls for a plain `*args: float`.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for with the type hinting https://stackoverflow.com/q/67649533/6609896. I think it may require the new PEP 612 -- Parameter Specification Variables but not sure. The problem with Protocol is that it doesn't seem to play nicely with Callable, so I can't pass a custom callable that matches the protocol - e.g. a python function or lambda, and must manually typehint callables to match the protocol which is a bit weird. It's maybe fine here since the Evaluate function needs to be typehinted in python anyway, however it arbitrarily restricts the sig of my scipy stub method

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. Procedurally I toyed with the idea of copying my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649533/how-to-typehint-a-function-which-takes-a-callable-and-its-args-as-parameters-e/67674066#67674066 to here but decided against it.